# Is it possible to center text in select box?

Tags: css

I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/ilyaD/KGcC3/

HTML:

```html
<select name="state" class="ddList">
    <option value="">(please select a state)</option>
    <option class="lt" value="--">none</option>
    <option class="lt" value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option class="lt" value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option class="lt" value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option class="lt" value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option class="lt" value="CA">California</option>
    <option class="lt" value="CO">Colorado</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```css
select { width: 400px; text-align: center; }
select .lt { text-align: center; }
```

As you can see, it doesn't work.  Is there a CSS-only way to center text in the select-box?

Comment: In my Firefox it works correct :)

Comment: Doesn't work on chrome.

Comment: @Blazemonger I can imagine many situations in which having a design that looks symmetrical is more important than left aligned options for easing lexicographical scanning by humans. E.g. if I want to have a gender select option that fills the screen 100 % horizontally on a mobile device, it looks very odd that the texts 'Male' and 'Female' are pushed all the way left.

Comment: try text-align-last:center;

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible with plain CSS, and won't be possible to make completely cross-browser compatible.

However, using a jQuery plugin, you could style the dropdown:

https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery-ui-selectmenu-an-aria-accessible-plugin-for-styling-a-html-select.html

This plugin hides the `select` element, and creates `span` elements etc on the fly to display a custom drop down list style. I'm quite confident you'd be able to change the styles on the spans etc to center align the items.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20160328192510/http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery-ui-selectmenu-an-aria-accessible-plugin-for-styling-a-html-select.html

Here is the improved version now that filamentgroup's is no longer maintained. https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui

Answer (score 484):

There is a partial solution for **Chrome**:

```
select { width: 400px; text-align-last:center; }
```

It does center the selected option, but not the options inside the dropdown.

Comment: Not supported on Safari

Comment: Not supported on Edge either.

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox, but what works in Firefox is `text-align: center`.

Comment: `width` is not necessary.

Comment: Damn, this is perfect, also works on latest Firefox... +rep

Comment: this is perfect for me. modding an NWJS app where data results are presented in disabled inputs.  `text-align-last:center;` shows results properly centered now.

Comment: Works fine (even on Safari), just tested it out :).

Answer (score 98):

That's for align right. Try it:

```
select{
    text-align-last:right;
    padding-right: 29px;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

the browser support for the `text-align-last` attribute can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-align-last.asp 
It looks like only Safari is still not supporting it.

Comment: This should be the top answer, a simple & pure CSS solution that worked perfectly for me (although I changed `text-align-last: right;` to `center` as I wanted the labels in the middle).

Comment: This answer rocks! Nowhere else did I find such a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer should be the selected as this totally works!

Comment: text-align-last:center; alone works for me in chrome and firefox. not in edge and I would bet on safari neither.

Comment: top notch answer

Comment: This doesn't work in any mobile browsers. Which is where primarily I would like it to work.

Comment: To be clear for those finding this answer, this gives a centered-ish effect if your options are similarly sized, but it's not actually centering things, just aligning them right and adding padding.  In my case, I have options ranging from 1 - 5 characters, so it looks very odd to have them all aligned right, because the spacing is not even between the left & right side.

Comment: @bjg222 please take a look at the first comment (by @JVG) that may help with your specific case.
Also, my answer above (the most voted) suggests `center` instead of `right`

Answer (score 68):

Yes, it is possible. You can use **text-align-last**

```
text-align-last: center;
```

Comment: This seems to center the value displayed in the select when closed.  The options in the dropdown are still aligned to the left (at least in Chrome as of Sep 2019)

Comment: Yes I want to display in the center and it's correct

Answer (score 65):

2020, Im using:

```
select {
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: center;
    -moz-text-align-last: center;
}
```

Answer (score 63):

You have to put the CSS rule into the select class.

**Use CSS text-indent**

**Example**

```
<select class="day"> /* option 1 option 2 option 3 option 4 option 5 here */ </select>
```

**CSS code**

```
select { text-indent: 5px; }
```

Comment: Either I didn't get it, or it simply does not work for aligning the text

Comment: text-indent... Interesting, I didn't know about that property. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This will only work for one specific option, text-indent depends on how much horizontal space takes the text of the option in relation to the selectbox width, so this is an incomplete answer, i'm amazed it got 43 upvotes, the proper answer using text indent was provided by Mr Smee above.

Comment: An interesting idea, but it won't work with a percentage so how can you center every single item?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using text-indent: 50% will center the option for you inside the select.

Comment: Indentation is not the same as centering.

Answer (score 22):

just using this:

```
select {

text-align-last: center;
padding-right: 29px;

}
```

Comment: You do not need to include "padding-right: 29px;" if you are using "center". I suspect you have because you copied Aly-Elgarhy's answer from Oct 25 '16.

Comment: When you copy from someone's answer you should mention their names.

Comment: Nop , i copied that directely from my Code as it is , that's why i puted the padding-right , may be i copied the solution from another one into my code , and then i copied the solution from my code into stackoverflow.

Answer (score 21):

```css
select {
  text-align: center;
  text-align-last: center;
}
option {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<select>
   <option value="">(please select a state)</option>
   <option class="lt" value="--">none</option>
   <option class="lt" value="AL">Alabama</option>
   <option class="lt" value="AK">Alaska</option>
   <option class="lt" value="AZ">Arizona</option>
   <option class="lt" value="AR">Arkansas</option>
   <option class="lt" value="CA">California</option>
   <option class="lt" value="CO">Colorado</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This was the only solution that helped me +1

Comment: May 2020 - This does not work on Safari (or any browser on all iOS devices)

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox 109.

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome or Safari on macOS

Answer (score 17):

This JS function should work for you

```
function getTextWidth(txt) {
  var $elm = $('<span class="tempforSize">'+txt+'</span>').prependTo("body");
  var elmWidth = $elm.width();
  $elm.remove();
  return elmWidth;
}
function centerSelect($elm) {
    var optionWidth = getTextWidth($elm.children(":selected").html())
    var emptySpace =   $elm.width()- optionWidth;
    $elm.css("text-indent", (emptySpace/2) - 10);// -10 for some browers to remove the right toggle control width
}
// on start 
$('.centerSelect').each(function(){
  centerSelect($(this));
});
// on change
$('.centerSelect').on('change', function(){
  centerSelect($(this));
});
```

Full Codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxyovL

Comment: It works for all Safari browsers even after May 2020 changes

Answer (score 9):

I have always gotten away with the following hack to get it to work with css only.

```
padding-left: 45%;
font-size: 50px;
```

padding will center the text and can be tweaked for the text size :)

This is obviously not 100% correct from a validation point of view I guess but it does the job :)

Answer (score 7):

**Alternative "fake" solution if you have a list with options similar in text length** (page select for example):

```
padding-left: calc(50% - 1em);
```

This works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. The trick is here to push the text
from the left to the center, then substract the half of length in px, em or whatever of the option text.

[image]

***Best solution IMO (in 2017) is still replacing the select via JS and build your own fake select-box with divs or whatever and bind click events on it for cross-browser support.***

Comment: Works in Chrome, but in IE it looks bit off to right than in the center.

Answer (score 6):

try this :

```
select {
    padding-left: 50% !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: as of October 2020, this solution works on Chrome, Safari, and Brave. (I didn't test in other browsers). Thanks a lot hmahdavi

Answer (score 5):

Not quite Centering but using example above you can make a left margin in select box.

```
<style>.UName { text-indent: 5px; }</style><br>

<select  name="UserName" id="UserName" size="1">
    <option class="UName" selected value="select">Select User</option>
    <option class="UName" value="User1">User 1 Name</option>
    <option class="UName" value="User2">User 2 Name </option>
    <option class="UName" value="User3">User 3 Name</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why not just add `text-indent` to `<select>` tag like @marc carreras said?

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me:

```
text-align: center;
text-align-last: center;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't really customise `<select>` or `<option>` much. The only way (cross-browser) would be to manually create a drop down with divs and css/js to create something similar.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't find any solution, you can use this trick on angularjs or using js to map selected value with a text on the div, this solution is full css compliant on angular but need a mapping between select and div:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('selectCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.value = '';


  }
]);
```

```css
.ghostSelect {
  opacity: 0.1;
  /* Should be 0 to avoid the select visibility but not visibility:hidden*/
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
.select {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-guide-concepts-1-production</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-app ng-controller="selectCtrl">
    <div class=select>
      <select ng-model="value" class="ghostSelect">
        <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
      <div>{{value}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this could be useful for someone as it took me one day to find this solution on phonegap.

Comment: its non in the middle!

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot center the option text within a select, you can lay an absolutely positioned div over the top of the select to the same effect:

```
#centered
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 818px;
  height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 24pt calibri;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
}

#selectToCenter
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 840px;
  height: 40px;
  font: bold 24pt calibri;
}

$('#selectToCenter').on('change', function () {
    $('#centered').text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});

<select id="selectToCenter"></select>
<div id="centered"></div>
```

Make sure the both the div and select have fixed positions in the document.

Answer (score 1):

On your select use **width: auto** and no padding to see how long your text is.
I'm using 100% available width on my select and all of my options have the same length, this allows me to use very simple css.

**text-indent** will move the text from left, similar to padding-left
**120px is my text length** - I want to center it so take half of that size and half of the select size, leaving me with 50% - 60px

```
select{
  width: 100%;
  text-indent: calc(50% - 60px);
}
```

**What if I have different sizes of options?**

It is possible, however, the solution will not be a pretty one.
The former solution might get you really close to being centered if the difference between options isn't like 5 characters.

**If you still need to center it more precisely you can do this**

**Prepare this class:**

```
.realWidth{
   width: auto;
}
```

Apply onChange listener to select element
In that listener **apply .realWidth** to the select element with

```
const selectRef = document.getElementById("yourId");
selectRef.classList.add("realWidth");
```

Get access to the real width of the option.

```
const widthOfSelect = selectRef.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;
```

widthOfSelect is the width you are looking for. Store it in global/component variable.
Remove the realWidth, you don't need it anymore.

```
selectRef.classList.remove("realWidth");
```

**I am using react**, **I'm not sure this will work in vanilla**, if not you have to find another solution.

```
<select style={`textIndent: calc(50% - ${widthOfSelect}) %`}> ... </select>
```

Another solution, however, that is a bad one could be creating the CSS classes with js and putting it to head.

**PROS:**

1. probably works, I haven't tried the dynamic solution but it should work.

**CONS:**

1. if the program is not fast enough user will see the width: auto taking place and thus wonder what's going on. If that is the case just create duplicate select, hide it behind something with a higher z-index and apply the on select listener from the original to the hidden duplicate.
2. Might be hard to use if you cant inline the style because of vanilla limitation, but you can make a script to optimize the appendChild to the head.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue where a client was insisting on this, and they were on a Mac and and iPhone.

I wound up using media queries and a percentage padding for padding-left. Was this a satisfying solution? Not at all, but it let me move on.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:
Use padding-left

```
select{
   padding-left:2rem
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
My work-around was to change to a fixed size font in the style section:

```css
option {
  font-family: Courier New;
  width: 12ch;
  font-size: 14pt
}

select {
  font-family: Courier New;
  width: 14ch;
  font-size: 14pt
}
```

In body I padded the shown options with underlines to make them the same length.
Note used underlines on both sides to center display:

```html
<select onchange='O.src=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value' align="center">
  <option value="" align="center">___(none)___</option>
  <option value="https://www.247backgammon.org/" align="center">_Backgammon_</option>
  <option value="https://www.247klondike.com/klondikeSolitaire3card.php" align="center">__Klondike__</option>
  <option value="https://www.247minesweeper.com/" align="center">_Minesweeper</option>
  <option value="https://sudoku.com/" align="center">
    <p>___Soduku___</p>
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not 100% yet, but you can use this snippet!

text-align-last: center; // For Chrome
text-align: center; // For Firefox

Doesn't work on Safari or Edge, for now!

Answer (score -2):

if the options are static, you could listen for the change event on your select box and add padding for each individual item

```
$('#id').change(function() {
    var select = $('#id');
    var val = $(this).val();

    switch(val) {
        case 'ValOne':
            select.css('padding-left', '30px');
            break;
        case 'ValTwoLonger':
            select.css('padding-left', '20px');
             break;
        default:
            return;
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not a good ideia putting padding-left for each word. How about this words comming from de database and are dynamic?