# Text-aligning CSS not working in Chrome or IE. Yes in FireFox

Tags: html, css

I try all the different code for center aligning and not work in chrome or IE. Here is my code. I'm trying to align center text in the dropbox. Any suggestion?

```
  .dropdownmenu,
  .dropdownmenu option 
  {
    text-align:center!important;
  }

  <select class="dropdownmenu" name="memo[How did you hear about us?]" ">
   <option  value="Relativity website">Relativity Website</option>
   <option  value="Internet search">Internet Search</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to center text in select box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813528/is-it-possible-to-center-text-in-select-box)

Comment: Is not the same. They are using Jquery. I using Word Press

Answer (score 1):

In my remember, modify `select` style is only allowed by Firefox

You can walk around by using a jQuery plugin which simulates a select with `div` and others tags