# How to center text of select box in IE10

Tags: html, css

Hello guys i have a drop down select box i have used the text-align:center; for centering the

text but its only working in Firefox not in IE, Chrome.

here is the code:

```
.option
{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to center text in select box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813528/is-it-possible-to-center-text-in-select-box)

Comment: I have read somewhere that this cant work in IE

Comment: Could you share the markup? Is it just select with options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding `padding-left` on the select element.

This doesn't produce exactly the same result as `text-align:center`, but maybe it's close enough for you.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PYwWc/)**

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a div, and use margin: auto; for the div. (if you want to center the whole element)