# Centre align drop down list text

Tags: html, css

I have a simple down drop list which displays five different games consoles. Is it possible to centre align the text? I've tried center aligning it, however, this doesn't help.

html

```
<select class="consoles">
  <option value="0">Xbox One</option>
  <option value="1">Playstation 4</option>
  <option value="2">PC</option>
  <option value="3">Nintendo Wii</option>
</select>
```

css

```
.consoles {
  width: 120px;
  height: 37px;
  text-align:center
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813528/is-it-possible-to-center-text-in-select-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `.consoles {width: 120px; height: 37px; padding-left:10px;}`

you can adjust padding-left to suit your needs.
 http://jsfiddle.net/PawelK/CN8mr/

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813528/is-it-possible-to-center-text-in-select-box), this is not possible with plain CSS. However, you can use a jQuery plugin to style the dropdown. When the page is loaded, the plugin converts the `select` element into `span` elements on the fly.