# Align Text Center in Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have currently got myself a nice styled select box which I made:

http://jsfiddle.net/B2rS6

However, if I were to set the width longer than the relative or have a really long option like the below, the text would not be centered.

```
<option>This is a really long option that will distort the width of the selections</option>
```

Is there a way I can style it so that it will center the text in the select across browser? I don't care if it's javascript or css. Just need something that will work.

Comment: Your question is very confusing, I don't see any problem with alignment here, if you have an option of  a long text, the select will grow to contain that long text and except that, it looks fine. If you want to limit the width of the select, try using `max-width` property.

Comment: @KingKing The text in the `select` is what I'm trying to center. I don't care for the width of the element.

Comment: you want text align center of option value. right? @Spedwards

Comment: @Boopathi More or less, yes.

Comment: You may use a custom select like [this one](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and probably you can make it's  text center aligned.

Comment: [Here](http://www.roblaplaca.com/docs/custom-selectbox/) is another one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/boopathirajan/3mAm8/ check this @Spedwards

Comment: @Boopathi Doesn't work in Chrome or FF

Comment: You just need to center your option box http://jsfiddle.net/B2rS6/12/ like this ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Nope. Add a really long option.

Comment: @Boopathi not working on opera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I think* you can achieve this is with a plugin, I happen to know of an amazing one: http://formstone.it/components/selecter

A normal select box is very hard to style... soon though we will have the power to do so with the infamous *Shadow DOM*. Here is a normal select menu with the power of JS added (Thanks to Ben Plum).

*There are external files included in the "resources", feel free to grab them*

http://jsfiddle.net/wChTk/

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col50">
            <select>
                <option value="de_DE-test">Category 1</option>
                <option value="en_US-test">Category 2</option>
                <option value="es_ES-test">Category 3</option>
                <option value="es_MX-test">Category 4</option>
                <option value="fr_FR-test">Category 5</option>
                <option value="fr_CA-test">Category 6</option>
                <option value="it_IT-test">Category 7</option>
                <option value="pt_BR-test">Category 7</option>
                <option value="sv_SE-test">Category 7</option>
                <option value="zh_CN-test">Category 7</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Using CSS. Set `width` and `text-align`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B2rS6/7/)

---

I read some documentation now... And afraid, isn't possible with plain CSS.
You can use something, what one man recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813528/is-it-possible-to-center-text-in-select-box) and redesign

Answer (score -4):

set `text-align: center;` for select