# How do I center text in the <option> element?

Tags: css

I want to center the text when using: < select > < option > . I customized < select > to a nice rectangle button, but the text is aligned to the left and I don't know how to target it in CSS so I can center it.

So far I have tried:

```
 option { text-align:center; }
```

and

```
 option[value=0] { text-align:center }
```

No luck..

Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/xtsx68pf/

I need the text to be centered. How do I do that with the < **option** > element?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `<select>` element's appearance is somewhat tightly controlled by the OS. If you want flexibility and customizability, you might want to explore a JS-based replacement like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

Comment: Just read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813528/is-it-possible-to-center-text-in-select-box

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, there is not a cross-browser solution using only CSS. I believe text centering does work on Firefox though.

You could do a left margin like so:

```
select {
  text-indent: 10px;
}
```

but this may not meet your requirement.

You can also look into plugins for stylized select elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select, option {
padding-left: 30px;
}
```

fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xtsx68pf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what eBrian said but try using percentages.

```
    select {
width:106px;
height:40px;
border:0;
background-color:#eee;
color:grey;
font-size:14px;
-webkit-appearance:none;
outline:none;
border-radius:0;
**text-indent: 25%;**
```

Seems to look alright