# How could i change the alignment on my listbox

Tags: html, css

like what i said on the title. I tryd to used `text-align` if you can notice in my code below.

```
<SELECT style="font-size: 32px; 

           margin-left: 5px;
           text-shadow: 1px 0px 3px gray;
           font-family: Times New Roman;
           height: 43px;
           width: auto;`enter code here`
           color: #000;
           font-weight: bold;
           border: none;
           background-color: transparent;
           text-align:center;">

<OPTION Value="">CLASSROOM RATIO</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="">ENROLMENT END OF SCHOOL YEAR</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="">ENROLEMNT OF ALS LEARNERS</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="">FURNITURE RATIO</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="">NUMBER OF CLASSES BY SHIFT</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="">NUMBER OF CLASSES</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="">NUMBER OF COMPLETERS/PROMOTEES/GRADUATES</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="">NUMBER OF DROPOUTS</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="">NUMBER OF TEACHERS BY GRADE LEVEL</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="">NUMBER OF TRANSFEREES IN</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="">NUMBER OF TRANSFEREES OUT</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="">TEACHER DEPLOYMENT</OPTION>


</SELECT>
```

the out is like this:

````````````````````````````````````
 __________________________________
|CLASS ROOM RATIO                  |
```````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````

i want my list items will be in centered :

````````````````````````````````````
 __________________________________
|        CLASS ROOM RATIO          |
```````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````

I've been searching for 4hours , can someone give me an answer for this code ? pls help me.

Comment: you have two **hyphen** in text-align property

Comment: ow im sorry , its just mistake in typing my code here, but it doesnt matter. sorry .

Comment: @user3623027 thats probably a typo

Comment: It is not possible using css, but can be done with jQuery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813528/is-it-possible-to-center-text-in-select-box

Comment: @MatjažMav nope , you can use text-indent

Comment: Yeh, just noticed that :) we are constantly learning

Comment: i can't use text indent bro , because some options are long text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to align it using `text-align`.
So the only way out is using `text-indent`

```
option
{
    text-indent: 5px; 
}
```

Add the above to your option's css

Comment: the problem with  indent is when i select the long text for example `NUMBER OF COMPLETERS/PROMOTEES/GRADUATES` it does not suit in the list box. btw txt bro

Comment: @Paul like for a long text , give text-indent:1px , for a short one give text-indent:5px and so on. So basically set a different value for different options