# text-align center does not works on mobile browsers

Tags: css, responsive-design, text-align

I wrote `text-align=center` and tried on desktop browsers and worked successfully but didn't work on mobile browsers (safari and chrome on iPhone).

How to write right css to center text on mobile browsers?

```css
.mobileCss{
    width:50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<select class="mobileCss">
    <option>aaaaaaaa</option>
    <option>bbbbbbbb</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please, provide more information(HTML, CSS, Jquery, Jsfiddle and etc).

Comment: Which mobile browser have you tried?

Comment: Possible answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10813603/3194491

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to try is use padding-left on your select.

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual way of accomplishing text centering within regular select box in plain CSS. You will have to use javascript/jQuery whether you want or not.

You can:

1) Use a javascript/jQuery plugin to calculate size and center the text everytime it changes value

2) Create a completely custom independent select box