# How to make center integers in SELECT attribute css?

Tags: html, css

I need to center integers in my select attribute, but I have no idea,  how to make that, because `text-align:center` is not working, `display:block` and `margin:auto` is not working too.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/8nz2gcu5) is a jsfiddle link

Comment: research before answering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813528/is-it-possible-to-center-text-in-select-box

Answer (score 0):

For chrome:

Use `text-align-last:center;` instead of `text-align: center;`

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8nz2gcu5/6/) jsfiddle link

Use `padding-left: 80px;`

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8nz2gcu5/8/) jsfiddle link

OR drop the `<select>` and use an `<input type="text">` and a  `<div>` to give you the exact feel of a select list but with the ability to do everything as it will be a `<li>`.