# center align css3 styled drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm using this example to style drop down menu using CSS [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/99ptc818/1/).

HTML:

```
<div class="styled-select blue">
  <select name="brand" id="brand">
    <option>Choose category first</option>
    <option>Brand one</option>
    <option>Brand two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.styled-select {
    background: #fff url('http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/20-20-1383000fade3dbdf3e93972212606011-Arrow.png') no-repeat 10px center;
    height: 31px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.styled-select select {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 31px;
    width: 103%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    /*padding-left:48%*/
}
```

But the text is aligned left not centered. There's a way to set padding left to the select tag itself but does not center text correctly so how to fix this?

Comment: your fiddle shows the text aligned center, so I can't understand your issue

Comment: My chrome-v50... is showing centered

Comment: chrome 49 does not

Comment: it is centered in Firefox for me http://s31.postimg.org/subzh3i17/center.png

Comment: Edge does not center the text too

Comment: updated chrome to v 50 and still not centered @Salathiel Genèse

Comment: Sorry, I'm using but firefox-45... this time around.

Apologize!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to center text in select box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813528/is-it-possible-to-center-text-in-select-box)