# How to set and align ion-select in center on toolbar in ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to set select-option on toolbar in ionic, but I'm unable to align it to center, I have tried many things... by using these methods I'm unable to do so,

```
<div text-center>
     <label class="email">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
     </label>
 </div>
```

This method aligns input box to center but it doesn't align select-option to center. here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ghebgx?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

```
<div text-center>
<ion-item>

              <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming" interface="popover">
                <ion-option selected value="empty">empty</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="ps">PlayStation</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="genesis">Sega Genesis</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="saturn">Sega Saturn</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="snes">SNES</ion-option>
              </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
</div>
```

still the results are same

```
.item-select{
    position: initial;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width:40%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This also doesn't affect, can anyone tell me how to set select-option to center on the toolbar in ionic?

Comment: Can you provide the `stackblitz`? https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @gaurang Hi, take a look at this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813528/is-it-possible-to-center-text-in-select-box

Comment: If i understand well give a try with this line `.alert-radio-label { text-align: center; }`

Comment: @Sampath see my updated question with stackblitz link

Answer (score 1):

I think text-center will not work as ion-select is component. I have worked it around by using ion-select in grid.

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12" offset="4">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-select>
              <ion-select-option selected>item 1</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option>item 2</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put percent for margin-left, margin-right, max-width and width percentage. Below are my example (just take the style):

```
<ion-select
    name="remark"
    formControlName="event"
    interface="popover"
    [(ngModel)]="remark"
    style="max-width: 100%; width: 80%; height: 25px; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%;"
    (ionChange)="onChange($event)"
    placeholder="Sila pilih satu"> 
        <ion-option value="Y">Yuran</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="L">Lain-lain Bayaran</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```